# How to activate Postgresql statistics collector?

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

i'm trying to use pg_monz template on zabbix to monitor my postgresql database.
I've made the configurations for the template but then i've found out that I need
to enable the statistics collector in postgresql.conf. I've done that by discomenting
these lines

```
track_activities = on
track_counts = on
track_io_timing = on
track_functions = all                   # none, pl, all
track_activity_query_size = 1024        # (change requires restart)
update_process_title = on
stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
```

and then i restarted the server. But there are no tables pg_stat_* on
any database of my postgres!!! how these tables are created?

Comment: The `pg_stat_xxx`  tables/views are inside the `pg_catalog` schema. Did you check that?

Comment: which database? i'm new to postgresql, in psql i've typed \l and it just shows 3 databases: postgres, template0 and template1. what pg_catalog is supposed to be?

Comment: The schema `pg_catalog` is available in every database, but the template databases are not interesting for you. Just connect to the `postgres` database and do a `select * from pg_stat__xxxx` (you need to connect as a superuser though)

Comment: it works!!! thanks. but no statistics are showing on zabbix. only number of postgresql process and if service is running.

Comment: i've discovered. I need to edit pg_hba.conf to trust my postgres user without a password. please @a_horse_with_no_name post your answer for my question and I will accept it. thank you!